# How to control all file extensions or not another directory? in just one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, file, operating-system

I have too many files like a "2020_01_20.jpg" and in my code I change file's extension like `2019_01_20.png`.

When I run the program, I check file if I changed its extension before. I do this algorithm by looping, but I want to get this done in a single line.

How can I do that in Python?

```
path='mydirectory/jpgfile/'
os.chdir(path)
files=os.listdir()

jpg_files = [file for file in files if file[-4:].lower()=='.jpg']

for file in jpg_files:
    pngfile="mydirectory/pngfile/"+file[0:-4]+".png"
    if(os.path.exists(pngfile)==False): #exist checking
              #code
```

Comment: You can do this to check if all files exists in the dir: `files_exist = all([os.path.exists('mydirectory/{}.png'.format(file[0:-4])) for file in jpg_files])`

Comment: If you've already changed the extension then `jpg_files` won't have it in the list so it's a fairly redundant check... You've not shown it in your code but do you actually rename the files anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line return a list with the names of `.jpg` files that doesn't exist as `.png` files.

```
no_png_files = [file for file in jpg_files if not os.path.exists(file[0:-4]+'.png')]
```

Comment: That's works but think that jpg files and png files not inside same path...

Comment: I edited my sample code. Sorry for showing it the same path. But in fact they are not the same path.

Comment: You could change the path like you've already done (`path='...'` and `os.chdir(path)`) in your code. Now you should change it right before the `no_png_files = ...`.

Comment: i changed os.chdir() and it's works. Thanks for information!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can make use of `pathlib` here to iterate over your directory and change the extension, eg:

```
import pathlib

for jpg_file in pathlib.Path('mydirectory/').glob('*.jpg'):
    jpg_file.rename(jpg_file.with_suffix('.png'))
```

You don't need to worry about if you've previously renamed something as if you have, then it won't match the pattern `*.jpg` and so it won't attempt to rename it to start with.